# Calling a function and property the same way?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that when I call it, it let me without using (), why?

```
Public Class Socio

Private _antiguedad As Integer

Public Function RetornarAntiguedad() As Integer
        Return _antiguedad
    End Function
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim test = New Socio()
    test.RetornarAntiguedad <--- This works even though it doesnt have (), why?
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

It looks like it works like a property? Wouldnt it generate confusion between a function and a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB syntax, a function call doesn't require a trailing `()` when you capture its return value.

In your example above, you're calling the function as you would a method—without capturing its return value. Thus the Visual Studio IDE should automatically append the parentheses.

However, if you were to change it to this:

```
Dim test As New Socio()
Dim result as Integer = test.RetornarAntiguedad
```

...the parentheses are no longer required.

It's just VB.NET syntax, that's all. Nothing to worry about. Your code will still work.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis are optional and the compiler will therefore not return an error unless of course you are adding arguments.
I think it is due to the "flexible" design of VB.Net.